# What's the difference between PL/SQL variables and non-PL/SQL variables?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

What's the difference between PL/SQL variables and non-PL/SQL variables?

Comment: What is a non-PL/SQL variable? Are you talking about bind variables from a programming language or client; including those you create with SQL Developer's `variable` command? Substitution variables (e.g. `&var`)? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here about Non PL/SQL [variables](http://www.relationaldbdesign.com/programming-pl-sql/module2/non-pl-sql-var-bind-host.php) which are Bind variables:

> A bind variable is a variable that you declare in a host environment
>   and then use to pass runtime values.  These values can be character or
>   numeric. You can pass these values either in or out of one or more
>   PL/SQL programs, such as packages, procedures, or functions.

and PL/SQL [variables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_variable_types.htm) which I assume you mean the variables which we use in our queries

> A variable is nothing but a name given to a storage area that our
>   programs can manipulate. Each variable in PL/SQL has a specific data
>   type, which determines the size and layout of the variable's memory;
>   the range of values that can be stored within that memory and the set
>   of operations that can be applied to the variable.